# Can this generate all primes but not any composite numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, python

$\sqrt{24n+1}$ can generate all primes from 1 to 100 (except for primes from 2 to 12), without any composite numbers in between as long as it follows a few rules.
(assuming $\sqrt{24n+1}$ is an integer.)

1. If $n-1$ is a multiple of 5, $\sqrt{24n+1}$ will not return a prime.
2. If $n\div7$ gives a remainder of 2, $\sqrt{24n+1}$ will return a multiple of 7 including 7 itself.
3. If $n\div11$ gives a remainder of 5, $\sqrt{24n+1}$ will return a multiple of 11 including 11 itself.

So my question is, if I follow these rules, can I get all the primes?

I have a python script that tests this prime generator:

```
import math
n = 1
while True:
    num = math.sqrt(24*n+1)
    if float(int(num)) == float(num):
        if (n-1)%5==0:
            pass
        elif n%7==2:
            pass
        elif n%11==5:
            pass
        else:
            print('24 times '+str(n)+' minus 1 is a prime. The result is: '+str(num))
    if n>=400:
        break
    n+=1
```

If I delete the `n>=400` part can I generate all primes?

Comment: Note that every prime $p>3$ is relatively prime to $24$ and that $p^2\equiv 1\pmod {24}$  It follows that $p^2=24n+1$ for some $n$ and we are done.

Comment: $\sqrt{24n+1}=p$ is equivalent to $24n=p^2-1$. Every prime $p>3$ satifsies $p^2\equiv 1\mod 24$ , hence is of the form $\sqrt{24n+1}$

Comment: @lulu You were a bit faster :)

Comment: @Peter  not by much!

Comment: @lulu However, it won't generate *only* primes.

Comment: But the problem is some numbers like 25 can also be found using $\sqrt{24n+1}$. if n = 26, the result is 25. What I want is to skip these composite numbers, so if I run a program I only get prime numbers.

Comment: "expcept primes from $2$ to $12$ is not correct. $5$ for example CAN be generated with the desired expression.

Comment: @j3ff Of course $\sqrt{24n+1}$ need not be prime. Every odd number not divisible by $3$ can be written this way (If we also allow $n=0$, we can also get $1$)

Comment: All primes from 2 to 12 can actually be generated, but because I want to keep my python script short, it skips 2 to 12.

Comment: @Peter the problem is all odd numbers not divisible by 3 can be written this way so there will be primes and composite numbers generated. I want to achieve a prime generator that only generates prime numbers.

Comment: The question asks "can I get all the primes?"  The answer to that is Yes (well, at least all the primes\ $>3$).  Did you mean to ask "can a simple modification remove all the composites?"  The answer to that is No.  You get every number $\equiv \{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\}\pmod {24}$.

Comment: @j3ff This approach cannot be extended to identify the primes. We cannot classify easily the numbers $n$ for which we get a prime.

Comment: I wonder why you accepted the below answer. I expected that you want to refine this approach to get a prime number generator. Of course, the answer is correct , but what it says is what you already knew.

Answer (score 2):

All the primes bigger than $11$ will show in the sequence but also a lot of composite numbers too. For example $169$.

So no, this is not a prime generator.

Your python program will write that $169$ is prime and this is false.